# Handling Multiple ClickableSpan in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I've been stuck at this problem for long. What I'm having is a simple string `"This is a link and this is another link"`. I want to have both "link" words click-able, having different URLs to open in browser.

- The simplest way I can do is to set Click-able Span on both "link"
  words with different URLs, but the problem I'm facing is finding the
  start and end positions of the span. The text is dynamic, and I have
  to programmatically find the positions.
- One approach would be to find the first occurrence of the word
  'link', find the start and end positions and set the span, and then
  the second occurrence. But that is not reliable. The text may contain
  more than one kind of repeated words, like `"This is a cat link and
  this is another cat link"`. Here I have to link both "cat" and "link"
  words with different URLs via Click-able Span. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 9):

Try in this manner

```
String s="Cat link 1 Cat link 2 Cat link 3";
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
    String first ="Cat link 1";
    String second ="Cat link 2";
    String third ="Cat link 3";
    int firstIndex = s.toString().indexOf(first);
    int secondIndex = s.toString().indexOf(second);
    ClickableSpan firstwordClick = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            ///............
        }
    }; 
    ClickableSpan secondwordClick = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            ///............
        }
    }; 
    ss.setSpan(firstwordClick,firstIndex, firstIndex+first.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(secondwordClick,secondIndex, secondIndex+second.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setLinksClickable(true);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(ss,BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Please do the same with this one, String s="first second third first second third". The string may contain more than one repeated words which I have to linkify. Thanks!

Comment: this you can do your self also, add some efforts from your end too. Let me know if face difficulty in it

Comment: As I said, the text is dynamic. It may contain more than one kind of repeated word. The problem I'm facing is to find the start and end indexes of the repeated word that I have to linkify with different links. Suppose, the text contains the word 'cat' 5 times and 'link' 7 times, and I have to set Click-able span to each of them with different URLs. indexOf returns the first occurrence, but what about the others? I can get the nth occurrence of the word in a string, but I'm having difficulty tracking all of them. I hope you understand the situation here. @Fahim

Comment: I don't want to linkify 'Cat Link 1' or 'Cat Link 2'. I want to linkify them seperately, 'Cat' & 'Link' seperately, and all of their occurrences. I'm sorry if I'm unable to explain you the situation.

Comment: this is the way to add more than one link to text . add some logic yourself to achieve what you want. I am not here to do your whole code. Hope you understood.

Comment: You're still not getting what I'm trying to say. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: @Fahim This is the most awesome answer I ever used in SO. You saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot programmatically find the difference in the links, then you cannot expect anything else to be able to do it. As the developer, you need a system.

You need to be able to identify the clickable spans - since the links are unique, the text that identifies them must also be unique. This would be a problem for your users, most likely.

You can get an ordered list of URLs and then if the links are indistinguishable, simply use them in the order you receive. Or, you need to change the rules of creating the links or the order in which they are displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm getting what you're saying. But being provided this kind of data from the server end, I have to handle this scenario as well, if possible. What if the text that identifies the link are same? There must be a way to serve both texts with different URLs.

Comment: If the text is the same, how do you which URL to associate with each String? You have to have a system to make that decision right?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this would be to include an identifier before the link say `/*/` then using this find the start and end position for link. Once you have that first replace the identifier with a `""` and then click away.

Comment: Could you please explain what you're saying a little bit more?

Comment: so say your text is "This is a cat link and
this is another cat link" instead send a link "This is a cat /*/link and
this is another cat /*/link" as a marker to set clickable points .. then detect the position of this marker to get the start and end positions of your clickable text areas. Once detected simpley remove the the marker

Answer (score 0):

I have string something such **"you order with orderId {b1j2gh4b} has been claimed by bla bla sotre with phone number (1234124124)"**

I am using these braces so as to find out the index of of **orderID** and **Phone number**

```
 String notificationMessage = mArrListNotification.get(position).getMessage();
            boolean isPhoneNumberAvailable = false, isOrderIdAvailable = false;
            int phoneStartIndex = 0, phoneEndIndex = 0, orderIdStartIndex = 0, orderIdEndIndex = 0;

    //getting index on the basis of braces added to text
            if (notificationMessage.contains("(")) {
                isPhoneNumberAvailable = true;
                phoneStartIndex = notificationMessage.indexOf("(");
                phoneEndIndex = notificationMessage.indexOf(")");
            }
            if (notificationMessage.contains("{")) {

                orderIdStartIndex = notificationMessage.indexOf("{");
                orderIdEndIndex = notificationMessage.indexOf("}");

            }

            // we got the index so remove braces
            notificationMessage = notificationMessage.replace("(", " ");
            notificationMessage = notificationMessage.replace(")", " ");
            notificationMessage = notificationMessage.replace("{", " ");
            notificationMessage = notificationMessage.replace("}", " ");

            viewHolder.txtNotificationMessage.setText(notificationMessage, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            Spannable mySpannablePhoneNumber = (Spannable) viewHolder.txtNotificationMessage.getText();
            Spannable mySpannableOrderID = (Spannable) viewHolder.txtNotificationMessage.getText();
            ClickableSpan mySpanPhoneClick = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {

                    currentPosition = (Integer) widget.getTag();

                    String message = mArrListNotification.get(currentPosition).getMessage();
                    int startIndex = message.indexOf("(");
                    int endIndex = message.indexOf(")");
                    phoneNumber = message.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex);

     Log.i("Phone Number", phoneNumber clicked)

                }
            };
            ClickableSpan mySpanOrderClick = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    currentPosition = (Integer) widget.getTag();

                    String message = mArrListNotification.get(currentPosition).getMessage();
                    int startIndex = message.indexOf("{");
                    int endIndex = message.indexOf("}");
                    String orderID = message.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex);
    // Log.i("Order id", orderID  clicked)

                }
            };
            if (isPhoneNumberAvailable) {
                mySpannablePhoneNumber.setSpan(mySpanPhoneClick, phoneStartIndex + 1, phoneEndIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (isOrderIdAvailable) {
                mySpannableOrderID.setSpan(mySpanOrderClick, orderIdStartIndex + 1, orderIdEndIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
```